# No puedo editar mi proyecto

Tags: c#

necesito que me ayuden con las parte de un codigo, ya que no me deja editar mis datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Detalles:  Tengo 2 control de usuarios, desde el UserControl 1 paso los datos, al DatagridView del UserControl2 ,como en la imagen, tood bien, al dar click al boton editar debajo del DatagridView , me pasa los datos perfectamente, pal cambiar los datos y querer pasar eso me pasa otro dato nuevo.

Codigo en el bonton entrar.

```
       private void btnEntrarManzana_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Globales.RegVenta.tipo = 1; 

                Globales.RegVenta.nombre = tbxNombre.Text;
                Globales.RegVenta.unidad = tbxUnidad.Text;
                Globales.RegVenta.cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(tbxCantidad.Text);
                Globales.RegVenta.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxPrecio.Text);

                Globales.RegVenta.nombre2 = tbxNombre2.Text;
                Globales.RegVenta.unidad2 = tbxUnidad2.Text;
                Globales.RegVenta.cantidad2 = Convert.ToInt32(tbxCantidad2.Text);
                Globales.RegVenta.precio2 = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxPrecio2.Text);

                if (Globales.RegVenta.status.Equals(""))
                {
                    Globales.RegVenta.status = "NUEVO";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Globales.RegVenta.status.Equals("EDITANDO"))
                    {
                        Globales.RegVenta.status = "GUARDAR";
                    }
                }
```

Boton Editar del User Control1

````
     private void btnEditarManzana_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (dgvManzana.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Int32 selectedCellCount = dgvManzana.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
                    if (selectedCellCount > 0)
                    {
Globales.RegVenta.Nombre = dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   Globales.RegVenta.Unidad = dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   Globales.RegVenta.Cantidad = (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
   Globales.RegVenta.Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada].Cells[3].Value.ToString());


Globales.RegVenta.Nombre2 = dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada +1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   Globales.RegVenta.Unidad2 = dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada +1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   Globales.RegVenta.Cantidad2 = (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada +1].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
   Globales.RegVenta.Precio2 = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvManzana.Rows[Globales.FilaSeleccionada +1].Cells[3].Value.ToString());



                        Globales.RegVenta.status = "EDITAR";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("LISTADO VACIO");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```Agrego el archivo
````